# python 3.6.3 execute salt, receive UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, salt-stack

I am doing an Ops Web by django==1.11, and I want to use SaltStack to manage servers. After some days learning, I can do some simple tasks.

But, when I use python code to call `salt.client.LocalClient()`, and then call `local.cmd('minion', 'cmd.run', ['whoami'])`, I receive

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 22: invalid start byte.
```

And I used `salt minion cmd.run whoami` on the shell, I receive the same result, I believe this situation is resulted by Python 3 version.

How can I use SaltStack by Python 3 both in server and python salt?

Comment: Which version of saltstack do you use? [Python3 support is quite young](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/11995)

Comment: Hi, dahrens, I use the latest version 2017.7.

Comment: It looks like somewhere you are getting some data encoded in `cp850` or one of its close relatives. `0x82` is the `cp850` encoding of `é`. Not sure if this will be of any help.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Thanks for your time, I will try it.